How to add color to the numberbox
Hi all this is a simple devextreme code blocks.I want to create the numberbox border colour as red.can you help me how to perform that.
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { NumberBox } from 'devextreme-react';

const MyNumberBox = () => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(null);

  const handleValueChanged = (e) => {
    setValue(e.value);
  };

  const borderColor = value && value > 20 ? 'red' : ''; // Conditional border color

  return (
    <NumberBox
      value={value}
      showSpinButtons={true}
      onValueChanged={handleValueChanged}
      style={{ borderColor: borderColor }} // Apply inline style for border color
    />
  );
};

export default MyNumberBox;


I try to add style tag but it was not appearing.

import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { NumberBox } from 'devextreme-react';
import './sample.css';

const MyNumberBox = () => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(null);

  const handleValueChanged = (e) => {
    setValue(e.value);
  };

  return (
    <NumberBox
      value={value}
      showSpinButtons={true}
      onValueChanged={handleValueChanged}
      className={value>20 && 'red-color'}
    />
  );
};

export default MyNumberBox;

Simply add a class to NumberBox with a condition when value > 20.
sample.css
.red-color{
  border-color: red;
}

You can achieve this with out any extra node to the DOM tree

Since the devextreme-react NumberBox corresponds to an input tag, one way would be to enclose the NumberBox in a div with a conditional className and then apply styling to the input in the css file.
  const errorClassName = value && value > 20 ? 'red-input-border' : ''; // Conditional border color

  return (
    <div className={errorClassName}>
       <NumberBox
      value={value}
      showSpinButtons={true}
      onValueChanged={handleValueChanged}
    />
    </div>
   
  );

CSS:
.red-input-border input{
  border-color: red;
}


this will add one more node to the DOM tree
